# Is it possible to explicitly make a grid item appear always on the last row or last column?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to place a grid item to be always on the last row and / or on the last column of a grid. Even if I don't know how many rows or columns the grid might have. Is something like that possible?

This would be my grid:

```css
.columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 16.5rem));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

I only found placement by explicit rows or columns:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid)

Comment: change the order of the element, for example : `order:10` ?

Comment: Did you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid#Counting_backwards ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941387/is-it-possible-to-place-a-grid-item-explicitly-to-be-always-on-the-last-row-or-l/54941700#comment96645794_54941387); from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid#Counting_backwards

> We can also count backwards from the block and inline end of the grid, for English that would be the right hand column line and final row line. These lines can be addressed as `-1`, and you can count back from there – so the penultimate line is `-2`.

Comment: The thing is this only works if I also define the rows explicitly as well. https://codepen.io/benedikt-buchert/pen/wOMrOQ

Comment: Oops indeed counting backwards only work on the explicit grid =/

Comment: I got the bottom right to work with a combination of order and column placement. Not the bottom left though. https://codepen.io/benedikt-buchert/pen/wOMPgb

Comment: Sorry I confused myself grid-column-start: -1 and 1 do what I need. Order is not needed for my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *pseudo element* `:after` to place an element at the end of the grid - see demo below:

```css
.columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 16.5rem));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.columns div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}

.columns:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `order` property to place the element to the end - if any other *grid item* has `order` property, just give a large value. See demo below:

```css
.columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 16.5rem));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.columns div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}

.columns .last {
  order: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="last"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```